# Reading a local JSON file, no server

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm a Noob to AngularJS so not sure if this is possible but i have a local JSON file that i would like to read and display the contents on a web page....

I've seen some example of reading json but all seem to involve running a server... Is it possible to retrieve the data from just a file read?

something like below (which doesnt work)

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('C:\test.json').success(function (data){
        $scope.tables = data;
    });

}]);
```

Comment: That code will only work if you run a server . Otherwine NO.

Comment: If you're reluctant to install lots of server stuff then I'd suggest installing virtualbox and vagrant, and using a vm to get a dev environment / "server". After installing virtualbox and vagrant it's just two commands to fire up a new project/machine. https://box.scotch.io/

Comment: thanks guys, again another Noob question... but would a quick way to get this to work be installing NodeJS and creating an endpoint for my angular app to call and retrieve the file?. I remember seeing a Node module that would help me read the file contents and i could use a full file path to get it.. 

Id like to make it as simple as possible as others will be using the app locally so would need a similar set up